# Как построить график нормальных вероятностей в Python?

Tags: python

Ранее я работал в Statistica и проверял нормальность распределения остатков без каких-либо затруднений.

Мне нужен график следующего вида.

[image: пример графика из Statistica]

Как построить аналогичный график в Python если остатки хранятся в array **residuals**?

Comment: неплохо было иметь входные данные. Набор библиотек на вскидку numpy, pandas, matplotlib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример. Данные сотворил кое-как. Главное что вам нужно - [stats.probplot](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.probplot.html):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.random(size=100)

res = stats.probplot(x, plot=plt)
plt.show()
```

Распределение не нормальное, что видно по "усам":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]